# What is meaning of template function arguments?

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, sorting, c++11

I have came across following template function,

```
template<typename C, typename F = less<typename C::value_type>> void Sort(C& c, F f = F()){
    sort(C.begin(),c.end(),f);
}
```

Now, I look for  in [less](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/less/), and it suggests,

> Binary function object class whose call returns whether the its first
>   argument compares less than the second (as returned by operator <).

In above mentioned function what is use of less? It has only one argument.

Thanks.

Comment: less is a binary function object, so it takes two arguments. Less is used in here as a default comparison function.

Comment: In this case the meaning is to sort by functor less so template code is the same for ascending and descending sorting you just call it with different less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. `less` doesn't have 1 argument. It has 1 template parameter. Which is not the same as 1 argument.
Also it's a class not a function. More precisely it's a `functor` - a class with an overloaded `()` operator so it can be used as a function.

Consider an implementation like this

```
template<class T>
struct less 
{   
    bool operator()(const T& left, const T& right) const
    {
        return (left < right);
    }
};
```

`less<int>` can be called as

```
less<int> f;
f(a,b);
```

where a and b are `int`s.

So there is one template parameter (T == int), but there are 2 arguments (int left & int right).

Comment: I do not understand, if that template argument deduced to int, then? Or I am taking it wrongly?

Comment: Oh God I am really silly, I understand your point. It is not function argument. It is template argument.

Comment: `less<int>(a,b);` is wrong, you need to create a functor and you can then call `operator()` on it: `less<int> functor; functor(a,b);`

Answer (score 2):

> what is use of less? It has only one argument.

No, it only has one *template parameter*. The actual function call itself takes two arguments, both (const references IIRC) of the type specified in the template parameter.

Comment: +1. Agreed. Your answer is right. But in SO I can select only one correct answer.